# IntelliJ Maven Project not building

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Eclipse background and have recently moved to a new job and am using IntelliJ.

I have an existing Maven Project, and in IntelliJ it does not build. i.e. we run mvn commands to build and have a Payara serer to run it. I am trying to get 'HotSwap' working.  In order to do so< I need to get IntellliJ to build the Maven Project (multi-modules).

I have looked online and tried the following:

I added new modules:
[image]

But when I edit a java file, there is nothing being compiled, i.e. I don't see compilation errors:

[image]

Any ideas of how I can get IntelliJ to build the project?

Thanks

Comment: I don't actually see you trying to run a build. Also: just editing a java file shouldn't trigger a build, so what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have just added a src folder, and it looks like it may have fixed this. p.s. Ctrl-F9 to build is now doing something. It now complains that I don't have the output path specified.

Comment: Why do you have those 14 maven archiver modules?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to create a new Glashfish Server and then reference Payara.
On 'UPDATE' action you have to select Hot Swap classes.